# Why does git log --name-only downloads further objects for repos with --filter=blob:none

Tags: git

Given I cloned a repository with:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout <url>
```

Now the following command is really fast as expect:

```
git log --oneline -- '**/somefile'
```

However this command is very slow, despite the fact, that all information should be in the tree files which are already downloaded:

```
git log --oneline --name-only -- '**/somefile'
```

Checking the background activity, it is visible that git fetches further objects. Can this be avoided somehow? I need to get the full path of the file(s) in the commits.

The only option I can see is to do the plumbing myself, e.g. use something like gitpython to run over the raw tree objects. However, I would rather use pure git commands to archive the task (find  all commits with a given filename/basename).

Comment: It might be that you triggered copy/rename threshold detection, try adding `-C100% -M100%`.

Comment: Besides @jthill's suggestion, it's worth noting that partial clones have a lot of edge cases that have not been tightened up properly. This code is likely to evolve (perhaps a lot) in the next year or two.

Comment: @jthill unfortunately this does not work

Seems like I have to work around. At least the without `--name-only` it works fast.

Comment: Newer git versions work a lot better. It seems a lot of those edge cases have been solved in the last months. Note: I had to compile git myself, because the versions in the distributions lack behind a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to do it is going to be

```
git log --pretty=%H -- '**/somefile' | git diff-tree -r --stdin --name-only
```

and then fill in the subject lines as needed, say an awk to supply them from a sideband `git rev-list --oneline --no-abbrev @`

Comment: Not that is not it. It still triggers to download the blobs. At least with git 2.25.1. Maybe it works better in a newer version.

Comment: I'm on 2.37 so yeah. I did test, your command still fetches blobs and mine doesn't, but it seems [@torek's scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73365974/why-does-git-log-name-only-downloads-further-objects-for-repos-with-filter-b/73405352?noredirect=1#comment129571715_73365974)'s playing out as he predicted.  edit: yup. Just built 2.25.1, it's misbehaving.